# Keras - How to visualize confusion matrix, when using validation_split

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

I've trained a model and used `validation_split=0.2` on the fit method, like so:

```
history = model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.2, epochs=700, batch_size=10, verbose=1,callbacks=[tb, checkpoint])
```

best weights were saved as an hdf5 file. Since the splitting of the data was done by Keras validation_split, I do not have the test set available. How can I plot a confusion matrix without the test set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation of fit()](https://keras.io/models/model/):

> validation_split: Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the training data
>   to be used as validation data. The model will set apart this fraction
>   of the training data, will not train on it, and will evaluate the loss
>   and any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch. The
>   validation data is selected from the last samples in the x and y data
>   provided, before shuffling.

So you can easily calculate the validation data yourself by getting the last 20% of X.

The [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/9118ea65f40874e915dd1299efd1cc3a7ca2c333/keras/engine/training.py#L1657) seems to do exactly this:

```
       elif validation_split and 0. < validation_split < 1.:
            do_validation = True
            if hasattr(x[0], 'shape'):
                split_at = int(x[0].shape[0] * (1. - validation_split))
            else:
                split_at = int(len(x[0]) * (1. - validation_split))
            x, val_x = (_slice_arrays(x, 0, split_at), _slice_arrays(x, split_at))
            y, val_y = (_slice_arrays(y, 0, split_at), _slice_arrays(y, split_at))
```

It first get the splitting index (number of samples * 0.8) and then keeps the following part as the validation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look